# Show Wiki pages on quick launch in a MOSS Wiki Site

Tags: wiki, quick-launch

The Quick launch section of a MOSS wiki site only shows the initial Page under wiki pages.  I have to manually add the wiki  pages that I create  to the naviagtion in order to see them under the quick launch. Is there a way to automate this?

Also the 'show pages' option is inactive (unable to select) under Naviagtion settings of a  MOSS wiki site. Is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anyway to do this out of the box. The Show Pages option is only for SharePoint pages in a page library. Wiki pages would either need to be added manually or you could write a custom event receiver on the wiki library that adds to the quick launch from code.